# writing item in a text file in python

Tags: python

I have a program that does the following.

1. you enter an input

> ```
> python 1.txt apple 5
> python 1.txt orange 18
> ```

2. it will write the item and amount in the text file
   an example of the modified  text file

> ```
> apple : 5
> orange : 18
> ```

3. it is also checking for duplicate then add the amount with the existing amount if present like-

> ```
> python 1.txt apple 5
> ```

```
apple : 10
orange : 18
```

Problem: if the item doesn't exist in the text file or is not duplicated, add the item in the text file. At the moment this doesn't work

Here is what I have written-

```
import sys

def maj(texte, item, nombre):
    with open(texte, "r") as f_in:
        lecture = f_in.readlines()
        with open(texte, "w") as ouvrir:
            for line in lecture:
                line = line.strip("\n")
                mot, chiffre = line.split(" : ")[0].strip(" "), int(line.split(" : ")[1].strip(" "))
                if mot == item:
                    ouvrir.write("%s : %s" "\n" % (item, str(chiffre + int(nombre))))
                    ouvrir.close()
                else:
                    ouvrir.write("%s : %s" "\n" % (mot, chiffre))
                    ouvrir.close()
def main():
    entree = sys.argv[1]
    item = sys.argv[2]
    nombre = sys.argv[3]
    choix = str(entree)
    texte = choix.strip("[']")
    maj(texte, item, nombre)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You say, "the only problem," but you identify two, and they're both a little fuzzy. Could you please reduce the code you've provided to a [mcve]?

Comment: sure i can but i wanted to provide it so you can understand everything going on. I've edited my question sorry

Comment: After the modifications, the example was no longer **complete**.

Comment: ok ive tried to clarify better the problem and added back the exemple of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you can try this:

```
import sys


def maj(texte, item, nombre):
    lecture = []
    with open(texte, "r") as f_in:
        lecture = f_in.readlines()

    if len(lecture) == 0:
        with open(texte, "w") as ouvrir:
            ouvrir.write("%s : %s" "\n" % (item, str(nombre)))
            ouvrir.close()
            return
    else:

        is_present = False
        for e in lecture:
            if item in e:
                is_present = True

        if not is_present:
            with open(texte, "a") as ouvrir:
                ouvrir.write("%s : %s" "\n" % (item, str(nombre)))
                ouvrir.close()

        else:
            for i in range(0, len(lecture)):
                line = lecture[i].strip("\n")
                mot, chiffre = line.split(" : ")[0].strip(" "), int(line.split(" : ")[1].strip(" "))
                if mot == item:
                    lecture[i] = "%s : %s" "\n" % (item, str(chiffre + int(nombre)))

            with open(texte, "w") as ouvrir:
                for line in lecture:
                    ouvrir.write(line)
                ouvrir.close

def main():
    entree = sys.argv[1]
    item = sys.argv[2]
    nombre = sys.argv[3]
    choix = str(entree)
    texte = choix.strip("[']")
    maj(texte, item, nombre)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It assumes that you have txt file `1.txt` in the same directory as you python file (let's call it `your_app.py`) and that you run the program this way:

```
python your_app.py 1.txt apple 5
```

You can copy and paste the code and run it. It's working.

Comment: Thanks a lot i understand what i was doing wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

Read the entire text file and create a dict of  ->  pairs. This should look something like this:

```
kv_pairs = {}
for line in file:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    token, value = line.split(' : ')
    kv_pairs[token] = int(value)
```

Then add your new key / new value:

```
if new_key not in kv_pairs:
    kv_pairs[new_key] = 0
kv_pairs[new_key] += new_value
```

Then write the values out to the file again:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
    for k, v in kv_pairs.items():
        # format and print
```

It should be relatively elementary to integrate this into your existing solution.

Comment: thanks for answering im using the solution above now